# Two divs, taking the whole page, resizing issue

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that should take whole page while each one is 50% of the page (50vh) but once I apply that the resizing goes crazy and elements overlap when the size becomes smaller and smaller, any workaround? I would like to achieve the typical disappearing of whole page that it gets removed from viewport, not overlapping.

```css
#top {
  background-color: red;
}

#bottom {
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div id='top'>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <input id='testInputOne' type='text'>
</div>
<button id='testButton' type='button'>Test</button>
<div id='bottom'>
  <input id='testInputTwo' type='text'>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tr40z716/

I tried to add one more div that would hold the two divs but no help.

Comment: The 2 divs can't be both 50% of the height while having a button of X height between them. 2 x 50% + X = 100 + X.

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you need.

Comment: Noticed, but after taking that in fact it didn't help me. I want to achieve that the resizing works without any overlapping, which now occurs if you resize the page to become really small. If you remove the height, that's what I would like to achieve with the resizing at whole. It just disappears slowly, the content, the elements, without any overlapping.

Comment: I still don't get what you want. Can you explain what do you want the size is big and when is size is smaller separately? Also did you try `overflow: hidden`

Comment: I have made a guess on what you want and made this: https://jsfiddle.net/dinodev/9m1yLzvs/5/

Comment: I will that as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a guess on what you need and made this using flex-direction: column and flex-grow: 1.

jsfiddle.net/dinodev/9m1yLzvs/5

Comment: Nice done, it seems to work even with the input tag without overlap! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the page to be scrollable, there‘s no way to display 3 elements if 2 of them already take up the whole size of the page.

There are 2 Solutions. Either you scroll, then both `divs` can be `50vh` or you use the following css, wich makes the `divs` *50vh - the height of the button / 2*.

Note that also the margin / padding of all elements needs to be removed or added to the calculaction to prevent an overflow. For padding, you can also set `box-sizing: border-box`, so that the padding will be included in the normal height of the element and doesnt need to be added to the calculation.)

**Here‘s an example:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#top {
    background-color: red;
}
#bottom {
    background-color: blue
}
button {
    height: 20px;
}
div {
    height: calc(50vh - 10px)
}
```

```html
<div id='top'>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <input id='testInputOne' type='text'>
</div>
<button id='testButton' type='button'>Test</button>
<div id='bottom'>
    <input id='testInputTwo' type='text'>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Good answer HackerFrosch but the input field will always overlap the first div. javascriptzero must be more explicit about this input field!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions even I don' really understand your goal.

CSS :

```
    html, body{
        margin:0px;
    }
    h1{
        margin:0px;
        padding:10px;
        border:none;
    }
    #top {
        background-color: red;
        height:50vh;
        /* min-height:100px; 
        solution 1 if You remove the #mainContainer div
        and uncomment min-height*/
    }
    #bottom {
        background-color: blue;
        height:50vh;
        /* min-height:100px; 
        solution 1 if You remove the #mainContainer div
        and uncomment min-height*/
    }
    #mainContainer{
        display:grid;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2,50vh);
        /* Solution 2 : use the main container div
        use the display:grid
        Solution 2 is used by default here*/
    }
```

HTML :

```
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="top">
            <h1>Test</h1>
            <input id="testInputOne" type="text">
        </div>

        <div id="bottom">
            <h1>Test</h1>
            <input id="testInputTwo" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
```